# equation for lm graphics

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

I'm doing graphics with lm relation, and I want to archive and to plot for each one of them an equation `y=ax+b` with R². How can I do it?

```
lmfit <- geom_smooth(method="lm", se = T)

p <- qplot(x, y, data=Tab) + facet_grid(id ~., scales = "free") + lmfit
```

Comment: Downvoters should please leave a comment explaining how the question could be improved.

Comment: if you give a reproducible answer (see http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) you may get a more detailed answer (@Brian Diggs's seems right but does not tell you how to do *exactly* what you want ...); also see http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/d53807fa41b95cc0?pli=1 (which I got by googling 'ggplot "regression equation" add') and http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/msg/edba8578e45d525a

Answer (score 3):

Within `ggplot`, there is no direct way to do this.  You need to compute the regressions separately for each `id` and then extract the equation and R^2 from each of those.  Put those extracted versions in a dataframe (along with `id`) and use `geom_text` to display them.